# MVC - Load an image from URL into a bitmap. (async await)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, bitmap, asp.net-mvc-5, async-await

I want to load an image from a URL in the server side, and use the await syntax if possible.

In a WPF application I could do that:

```
var image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("http://..."));               
image.ImageOpened += (s, e) =>
 {
 }
```

In MVC, instead, I have the by default System.Drawing.Bitmap which dose not have an option to load from a URL.

Should I :

1. Add reference to System.Windows.Media.Imaging and use BitmapImage
   class wrapping it with **TaskCompletionSource**.
2. Somehow load the image using the Bitmap class.

A working code using one of the above with async/wait would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Should be quite simple:

```
private Task<Stream> GetStreamAsync()
{
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    return httpClient.GetStreamAsync(@"http://urlhere");
}
```

and call it:

```
private async Task GetImageAndDoStuff()
{
   Stream imageStream = await GetStreamAsync();
   using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(Image.FromStream(imageStream)))
   {

   }
}
```